# Блокировка stdout.readline при использовании Subprocess.Popen

Tags: многопоточность, python-2.x, subprocess

Мне необходимо без задержки выводить данные дочернего процесса. Я использую Subprocess.Popen для того что бы перехватить вывод консольного приложения. Но stdout.readlin блокируется и в итоге на экран попадает только первая строка (при завершении программы). Использовал перенос readlin в отдельный поток, но это не помогло. В чем может быть ошибка?
Приложение под win7

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading  import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()

p = Popen("example.py", stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()

while p.poll() is None:
try:
    line = q.get_nowait()
except Empty:
    pass
else:
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

При перенаправлении вывод может быть не построчно буферезирован (буфер не сбрасывается при выводе новой строки). Вывод становится виден по окончанию дочернего процесса, когда его буфер со стандартным выводом принудительно очищается.

Вы видите только одну строчку из-за ошибки в коде чтения (`p.poll() is not None` не значит, что больше нечего выводить).

Стоит упомянуть, что если вы ничего с выводом дочернего процесса не делаете, то просто не перенаправляйте его вывод: по умолчанию процесс будет писать туда же что и родитель.

Если перенаправляете, то укажите параметры, чтобы буферизацию дочернего процесса настроить. К примеру, [`python` принимает `-u`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', '-c', 'for i in range(10, 20): print(i)'],
                stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
with process.stdout:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):  
        print(line.strip()[::-1])  # reverse chars

process.wait()
```

Даже если дочерний Питон-скрипт вставит паузы между `print(i)`, вывод будет сразу доступен благодаря `-u` опции.

- `iter(process.stdout.readline, '')` используется, чтобы обойти [Питон 2 баг с буфером чтения на стороне родителя](https://bugs.python.org/issue3907)
- `bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True` используется, чтобы поведение на Питоне 2 и 3 похожее было (построчно буферизированный текстовый режим). Если не рассматривать ранние Питон 3 версии, то можно `bufsize=1` не передавать при чтении. `bufsize=1` контролирует буфер в родителе (*вне* дочернего процесса) — он не поможет получить вывод раньше, который в буфере *внутри* дочернего процесса может висеть.

На *nix, можно попробовать заставить программу думать, что она печатает в терминал (что часто включает построчный режим вывода), используя `pty` модуль или аналоги. См. [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279).