# Доступ к программе на Python из программы на C#

Tags: c#, python, wpf

Добрый день. Вопрос в следующем: Есть программа на WPF на C# и есть необходимость запустить из нее другую программу на Python в асинхронном режиме. Как в процессе выполнения 2ой программы, получать из нее промежуточные значения в коде на C# 1ой программы. Как научить их обмениваться данными, какие есть средства для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По своему опыту могу посоветовать использовать такие настройки для запуска процесса, если у Вас модуль на Python делает вспомогательную логику, например модуль на Python распознает рукописные цифры - то можно просто в Python вернуть результат распознавания через `print` и в C# получить результат как output созданного процесса:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = PyPath,
  Arguments = args,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

потом

```
using (StreamReader stream = process.StandardOutput)
{
  var output = stream.ReadToEnd(); // тут будет результат того что напечатал в консоль модуль на Python.
```

Для более гибкого взаимодействия можно воспользоватся IronPython.

Ну и конечно же ещё масса способов IPC - [Wiki - IPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: автор насколько я понял хочет во время выполнения данные получать. В этом случае стоит `-u` опцию передать, чтобы можно было бы построчно вывод читать (к примеру в jsonlines.org формате). [Связано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/730231/23044)

Comment: Хорошо, с минимальными добавлениями - работает. Но действительно хотелось бы построчно читать то, что выводит скрипт. А как Вы посоветуете получать информацию наоборот, в программе на Python из C# ?

Comment: @Anton, так `ReadLine()` метод тогда используйте :) Вы можете сделать свой стрим с ивентом на каждый ReadLine.. или просто используйте `ReadLineAsync()` метод.